# Modeling the probability of a uniform point on $[a, b]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was given the following exercise : Explain how to define a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ that corresponds to the intuitive notion of an uniform point on $[a, b]$.

And this is the solution :

> Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be defined as $f(x) := (b − a)x + a$. This
> function is an affine bijection between $[0, 1]$ and $[a, b]$. Let
> $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. We can define a
> probability measure $µ$ on $\Bbb R$ by setting $µ(B) := λ(f ^{−1}(B
> > \cap [a, b]))$ for any Borel measurable subset $B$ of $\Bbb R^n$ . The
> corresponding c.d.f. is given by $F(x) = 0$ if $x < a$, $F(x) = 1$ if
> $x > b$ and $F(x) = f^{−1} (x) = \frac{x−a}{b−a}$ if $x ∈ [a, b]$.

I do not understand the question the exercise is asking. What is "the intuitive notion of an uniform point on $[a, b]$" ? Are they looking for a probability where all points in $[a,b]$ have the same probability ?

Comment: All the points in $[a,b]$ having the same probability is naively attractive, but fails when you realise that probability is $0$, and that other continuous non-uniform distributions have the same property.  So an intuitive approach might be to consider equal probability of being in different sub-intervals of $[a,b]$ of equal width, and then say that the probability of being in a sub-interval is proportionate to its width. Make this rigorous and extend that concept to Borel sets and you have the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform means that the probability of a Borel set should be proportional to it's Lebesgue measure. Therefore we should define $\mu(E) = \frac{1}{b - a}m(E)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Their solution is a strange way to arrive at the same $\mu$.